# Разработка игрового движка на основе ECS

Tags: разработка-игр, шаблоны-проектирования

Разрабатываю игровой движок с использованием архитектурного подхода ECS.
Пожалуйста помогите ответить на следующие 3 вопроса:

1. Подход ECS настаивает, чтобы все компоненты хранились в массивах. Один тип компонентов - один массив. По идее такой подход позволяет уменьшит потребление памяти (уменьшение дефрагментации) и повысить производительность (удобно для кеша). Предполагается, что системы будут обрабатывать массивы нужных им компонентов просто итерируясь по ним. 
   Но... но предположим вам каждый кадр надо проверять столкновения между объектами. Т.к. все компоненты у вас в массивах, то придется сделать O(N*N) проверок. Катастрофическое падение производительности налицо. 
   Укажите пожалуйста лучший вариант решения проблемы: 

   **a.)** Если системе требуется, чтобы компоненты хранились особым образом - просто создаем отдельную структуру данных с теми же компонентами. Но придется синхронизировать состояние разных хранилищ одних и тех же компонентов.

   **b.)** ваш вариант.
2. Все движки с архитектурой ECS, которые я видел, придерживаются следующего правила: сущность не может владеть более чем одним компонентам каждого типа. 
   Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию: 2D игра с видом сверху-сбоку. Сущности надо иметь два коллайдера - один столкновений с окружением, второй для столкновений с пулями. Укажите пожалуйста лучший вариант решения проблемы: 

   **a.)** создать два разных коллайдера - StatixColliderComp и BulletColliderComp. Но это дублирование данных. 

   **b.)** Создать две разные сущности связанные друг с другом - одна "содержит" StatixColliderComp , вторая BulletColliderComp. Но придется синхронизировать состояние двух разных сущностей.

   **c.)** ваш вариант.
3. Учитывая ограничение: сущность не может владеть более чем одним компонентам каждого типа, как представить иерархию компонентов (например - дерево трансформаций)?

Comment: 1а, причем синхронизация то не нужна, просто одновременно добавляйте/удаляйте объекты их соответствующих структур.

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо. Следует ли хранить все структуры в одном месте(например - ComponentManager) или каждая система хранит нужную ей структуру компонентов?

Comment: Не являюсь профессионалом по ECS, но ЕМНИП ECS заточен на инкапсуляцию. Т.е. кому что надо, тот то так и хранит. Только что разделяйте, что есть структуры и данные, а что просто указатели. Впрочем возможно это заслуживает быть отдельным вопросом.